# Что делать с подозрительными вопросами от новичков?

Tags: обсуждение

Несколько раз встречал такую схему:

- Новичок задаёт вопрос "почему этот код не работает?" и даёт шматок кода.
- Шматок кода выделен инлайновым кодом вместо блочного.
- В коде пачка самых разнообразных ошибок от опечаток и синтаксических ошибок до принципиально неверных действий.
- Другой новичок исправляет часть ошибок кода вопроса (код по-прежнему нерабочий) и постит полуисправленный шмоток кода с таким же инлайновым выделением.

Как правило, у обоих рейтинг 1 или близкий к этому.

Последний пример такого вопроса: [Почему не работают градиенты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503642/178988)

Что с таким делать? У меня начинает создаваться впечатление что это не случайно. Но какую выгоду оно несёт авторам, я не понимаю. А может, это вообще боты, которые откуда-то вопросы перетаскивают? Может даже отсюда?

Comment: Не очень понял откуда "отсюда" они вопросы перетаскивают... =)

Comment: [Бритва Хэнлона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%A5%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) здесь применима.

Comment: @404, чем чаще что-то происходит, тем более вероятно, что оно не случайно.

Comment: Проверил ip и регистрационные данные - совпадений нет.

Comment: Федя отрезал **шматок** сала и запил стопкой водки.

Comment: @Igor?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: "шматок" - проверочное слово "шмат" :) - попытка пошутить

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505793/178988

Answer (score 20, accepted):

К сожалению, на этом сайте далеко не всегда благожелательно относятся к новичкам и начинающим айтишникам — «пробовать лень», «получилась фигня, плюем», «упертый новичек», — окрашивая их действия негативной коннотацией вместо того, чтобы охарактеризовать нейтральными выражениями, в чём они неправы. я психолог, а не программист — попробую предположить, где сплоховали вопрошающий и отвечающий [в рассматриваемом примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503642/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).

1. Многие поначалу не понимают, что бесплатные вопросы вида «сделайте за меня» особо нигде не в почёте. **Нужно подробно расписывать проблему, по возможности указывая, какие действия по разрешению предпринимались самостоятельно**.
2. Другая причина составления некачественного вопроса. Бывает, что бьёшься часами над решением проблемы, а она никак не поддаётся. Обессиленный, принимаешься спрашивать на форумах, составляя вопросы кое-как. И с опытными пользователями происходит, не говоря уж о новичках. В таких случаях **требуется отдохнуть или переключиться на другую тему, а возвращаться к вопросу только с новыми силами, пусть это психологически не всегда просто.** Тогда и качество вопроса заметно повысится равно как и шанс найти ответ самостоятельно.
3. Даже если уверены, что недочёт в коде топикстартера именно там, где Вам кажется, всё равно **проверяйте свой код на работоспособность прежде чем запостить ответ**, — он тоже может не заработать правильно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

Думаю, просто изучать и пробовать лень.

Обычный алгоритм действия впервые зашедшего человека:

Копипастим форматированный текст (код) в вопрос и отправляем. Даже если видим, что получилась фигня, плюем со словами -- "а, ..., не можете нормально сделать, так и получите ...".

Далее, какой-то упертый новичек, охочий до репы (ну, все его характеристики, думаю, очевидны), как можно быстрее, чтобы никто не опередил его в получении заветных баллов, копипастит это в ответ, лихорадочно правит и отсылает.

Наверное, просто не надо обращать внимание на  такое безобразие, можно лишь черкануть комментарий автору вопроса в котором написать, что небрежно оформленные вопросы не рассматриваются и посоветовать прочесть справку.

Comment: Я не о плохих вопросах, а о сочетании факторов: криво оформленный вопрос с собранием разных ошибок (как будто их собрали специально) от новичка с ответом плохого качества от другого новичка в течение часа. Ну неужели не странно, когда такие начинают регулярно попадаться? Или у нас просто так много новичков?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот интересно, скколько у нас в самом деле *новичков*? Т.е. людей, которые появились в течении месяца и задали меньше 3 вопросов. И общее количество, задавших меньше 3 вопросов. Кто-то у нас imho любил задавать запросы к статистике SO.

Comment: @avp, [примерно так](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/452226/last-users#messages)? Новичков меньше трех вопросов - 658, Всего задало меньше трех вопросов - 13723?

Comment: @Grundy, думаю, да, так. А много ведь таких новичков-то, почти в 3 раза больше среднего за 5 лет (в предположении, что все 13723 такие, кто сразу задал 1 или 2 вопроса  и ушел).

Answer (score 7):

Я сам новичок на портале, могу ошибаться, но мне кажется механизм может быть таким. Приходит новичок, он не может и не видит причин голосовать, не разобрался в механизме сайта, так как на это требуется некоторое время. Помещает первый вопрос, вместо корректного направления, рекомендаций, получает отлуп от парочки "старичков", в стиле что никто не собирается отвечать на его криво-оформленные вопросы. Он не голосует, не получает привилегии, он получает или не получает ответ и уходит. Через 2 недели или 2 месяца все повторяется, но уже под другим аккаунтом. Вместо вовлечения нового пользователя, получается текучка новичков. Пока они ждут ответа, они могут дать свой ответ, не особо стремясь его оформить - они ведь не вовлечены в работу ресурса и они не заинтересованы в долгоиграющем качественном ответе. Они просто перепроэцируют собственную ситуацию - мне нужен ответ, почему бы его не дать другому такому же нуждающемуся.

Мне кажется нужно просто максимально корректно объяснять механизмы работы сайта и почему вопрос скорее всего не получит ответов, а главное что нужно сделать, чтобы получить ответ и помощь. Насколько я могу судить, такой работой занимаются единицы и в текстах, которые встречают новичков изрядная доля негатива и открытого пренебрежения.

Comment: 1,862 репутации - уже не совсем новичок )

Comment: Теперь 16.1k, и «я новичок» звучит почти издевательски для большинства читателей. =)

Answer (score 5):

Не имеет значения, кто задал вопрос. Если вопрос можно улучшить: оставляйте соответствующие комментарии, и/или редактируйте его. Если вопрос нельзя улучшить—голосуйте «закрыть».

Аналогично, с ответами: не имеет значения, кто автор ответа. Если вы считаете ответ бесполезным, то голосуйте «против» и/или комментируйте и/или опубликуйте свой ответ.

В (маловероятном) случае, что целая череда вопросов/ответов создана ботами, можно опубликовать здесь на Мете с десяток ссылок на подозрительные по вашему мнению вопросы/ответы или нажмите «тревога» под одним из подозрительных вопросов и приведите ту же информацию там для модератора.

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы не сделать что-то типа **песочницы**? Пусть вволю развлекаются. Отсеивать на первом же вопросе? Дедовщина какая-то. Может что-то типа **тестов** реализовать, после изучения **правил** поведения на сайте? И периодически их давать проходить тем, кто уже давно тут, что бы не так обидно было.

Comment: Кому и за что обидно? Ничего не понял...

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что именно вы предлагаете тестировать? Из своего опыта: на oDesk (ныне Upwork) есть входной тест на понимание правил, прохождение которого открывает доступ к использованию возможностей сайта.

Comment: Мне кажется, что StackOverflow и получил свою популярность за счёт того, что была простая и быстрая регистрация. И желающие ответить так же быстро могли зарегистрироваться и дать совет.

Comment: Вводя сложные режимы регистрации как на хабре, появляется угроза того, что будет меньше контента (может быть и в угоду качеству, но не факт). А тут на русском стэке и так людей не много. Куча вопросов не отвеченны.

Comment: Как бы не появился на StackOverflow вопрос - "Как правильно ответить на вопросы при регистрации на StackOverflow")